# Batch File ignores environment variables with if statement

Tags: batch-file

I have the following batch file. Basically it scans a director which has files in pairs with the same name but different extension  *.TXT and .AVI.
If the Text file name corresponding to the AVI file name exists, the AVI file is not played. Otherwise it should be played by the specified application. 
It seems environment variables are the issue between the the loop and the if. 
I have read almost all related posts on Batch files which to do with environment variables. None of them worked. I also tried with and without EnableDelayedExpansion, but no luck.  Also tried == instead of EQU but no luck. All Echo statements are for Debugging.
Here is my attempt.

```
@echo off

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET  MyApp="C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"
ECHO MyApp is %MyApp%

SET PathToDB=C:\1
ECHO PathToDB is %PathToDB%


FOR %%X in (%PathToDB%\*.avi) DO (

    ECHO  Q.  %%X  

    SET ABC=YES 

    IF EXIST "%PathToDB%\%%~nX.txt" (

        ECHO Coressponding Text File Exists ....[%%~nX.txt]....

        SET  ABC=[NO]
    )


    ECHO  1  %ABC%
    ECHO  1  !ABC!

    if !ABC! EQU "YES"    %MyApp%      %%X
    if !ABC! EQU "YES"    !MyApp!      %%X

)
```

Thanks for any helpful suggestions

Comment: are you saying the problem is the last if-statement??

Comment: The last two if statements in the code seems are not evaluated correctly despite the the variable ABC has the value YES

Comment: This comment should be read in conjunction with the answer already provided. If you look at your line it reads `SET ABC=YES ` if I place it in quotes it reads `SET "ABC=YES "`. Now you should be able to see your issue.

Comment: Helps to read the help file for the command you are trying to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `EQU` only for numerical comparisons. Because you are comparing text you should use `==` but remember: the whole text (**each character**) at the left must be **identical** to the whole text to the right of the `==` operator. The condition in the IF-statement `if !ABC! == "YES"    %MyApp%      %%X` will never evaluate to true since the right part contains double quotes `"` and the left part doesn't. So it should be:

```
if "!ABC!" == "YES"    %MyApp% %%X
```